# Physical layer management entity services for 802.11

Tags: driver, ndis, wifi

I am trying to implement ExtSTA operation mode for 802.11. Can any body please tell me PLME(Physical layer management entity) services for 802.11 and how can we implement those..

Answer (score 0):

As you can understand from the name, **Physical Layer** doesn't belong to the driver, it's implemented in HW/FW.